# React UseEffect and UseState object undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, use-effect, use-state

In my ClientData.js

I am using useEffect to call an API(which is working), then using useState to set the API response.data to a variable(which is working).

The response.data is an array of objects which I then set equal to a local variable. But when I attempt to access the object parameter I get a object undefined error.

I think the problem might be is that the object is undefined due to it waiting for the API response.

This is what the object from the API looks like:

```
objTest={
  ClientDatabase: "21",
  ClientID: "21",
  ClientName: "21",
  ClientServer: "21",
  Country: "US - 21",
  DatabaseVersion: "21",
  Namespace: "21",
};

function SimpleSelect() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    

    const [objTest, setobjTest] = useState([]);

    const clientAPI =  useCallback( async() => {
       
      //returns an array of objects
           await axios({
            method:'get',
             url,
            auth: {
                username: user,
                password: pass
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
  
         
            setobjTest(  response.data)
    
      
  
      
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        });

    })
    useEffect( () => {
        clientAPI();
        

        
    }, [])
```

When I attempt to access the object it works using `console.log((objTest[0]));`

but when I attempt to access the objects parameter
like this:  `console.log((objTest[0].ClientDatabase));`

it returns

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClientDatabase' of undefined

This is the console log of response.data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s023Y.png)

The response.data is an array.

Comment: This syntax was working fine when I was using class instead of function and using CompetentDidMount instead of useEffect

Comment: Have you checked to make sure data.response is an array for certain?

Comment: @RameshReddy I console.log(objTest[0].ClientDatabase) a 10 lines below the useEffect statement. The syntax of objTest[0].ClientDatabase returns the undefined error.

Comment: @RameshReddy When I do objTest[0] it works and returns the object.

Comment: Are you logging it inside a useEffect that has a dependency of [objTest]?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis the console.log is out side the useEffect

Comment: put it inside; see my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You put the initial state as an empty array. That's why you can't access it's first element. you can either set a non empty array as the initial state like this

```
const obj=[{
  ClientDatabase: "21",
  ClientID: "21",
  ClientName: "21",
  ClientServer: "21",
  Country: "US - 21",
  DatabaseVersion: "21",
  Namespace: "21",
}];

const [objTest, setobjTest] = useState(obj);
```

or you can check if the array is not empty

```
objTest.length && console.log(objTest[0].ClientDatabase)
```

The api call will take some time fetch the data. The initial state is what gives you the error

```
<Select labelId="demo-simple-select-label" id="demo-simple-select" value={age} onChange={handleChange} > {objTest.length && objTest.map(myList => { return( <MenuItem key = {myList.ClientDatabase} value = {myList} > {myList.ClientName} + {myList.Site} </MenuItem> ) })} </Select>
```

Try this out

Comment: The initial state is an array that code snipt is what the object looks like.                 
  const [objTest, setobjTest] = useState([]);

Comment: @JavascriptDeveloperMaintwo - what do get from `response.data`? Is it an array?

Comment: okay then all you have to do is use `objTest.length && objTest[0].ClientDatabase`. The array is empty in the begining. It takes some time for the data to get loaded. or you can set a non empty array as the initial value

Comment: @TheAlpha93 This works but the problem is that I am attempting to map over the objTest for a material ui element select, which is not working: <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        onChange={handleChange}
        
      >
       
       {objTest.map(myList => {
         return(
         <MenuItem key = {myList.ClientDatabase} value = {myList} > {myList.ClientName} + {myList.Site} </MenuItem>
         )
       })}
        
      </Select>

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
useEffect( () => console.log(objTest[0].ClientDatabase), [objTest])
```

Comment: What's wrong with overwriting the array in his case? He has an empty array and he's trying to populate it after getting the response.

Comment: Ah I didn't see him state the data.response was an array

Comment: @PavlosKaralis I added a picture of the console.log(response.data) which I believe shows that it is an array

Comment: @RameshReddy I added a picture of the console.log(response.data) which I believe shows it is an array

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with when you're logging the data. You're logging it a bit early.

So to check the modified state you can use an additional `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(objTest.length > 0) {
    console.log(objTest[0].ClientDatabase)
  }
}, [objTest])
```

And when you want to use this in the JSX you can check if it's populated:

```
{
    clientArrTwo.length > 0 ? <Select labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={age}
        onChange={handleChange} >
        {clientArrTwo.map(myList => {
            return (<MenuItem key={myList.ClientDatabase} value={myList} > {myList.ClientName} + {myList.Site} </MenuItem>)

        })}
    </Select> : null
}
```